# Loading Laravel's providers in Zend Autoloader fashion

Tags: laravel, zend-framework, spl-autoload-register

I'm from Zend background, and started using Laravel just now. I feel laravel becomes heavy as it loads all the files. Even on local it takes `> 150ms` for simple GET call.

So I was wondering that is there a way that we can use [Zend's Autoloader](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) to load classes when it's called in class, or in similar fashion such that it won't load all classes all the time?

Comment: Laravel uses the composer PSR-4 autoloader (same one zend uses) so will only load required files. Where does the assumption that it loads all files come from?

Comment: I didn't dig deep, but `$providers` array make me think so.

Comment: It will only autoload required files, if you never use a source file it won't be loaded. That being said, there's a lot of files that are required to successfully handle a request (all the providers for example are required). It generally doesn't matter much because if you use a decent OPCache configuration the loading of files falls dramatically and the time taken for a request depends exclusively on the running code. Alternatevely if you want a more "stripped down" Laravel-like frameowork you can consider [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)

Comment: Understood. I know lumen, but I want blade and sessions as well. So using Laravel. Also I guess may be `php artisan serve` is slower than virtual host in nginx.

Comment: The built-in webserver is quite slower, and as I said, running OpCache will significantly help performance but it's not something to run in development because you really wouldn't want code to be cached while you're changing it.

Comment: make sense. Thanks